# What is process philosophy by Alfred North Whitehead?

Tags: reference-request, whitehead

## What I am trying.

I want to know this process philosophy that Alfred North Whitehead is talking about.

## Problem I am facing.

I read some articles and watched some videos on what this philosophy is. But I am not getting anything. they say everything is processed. They say there are "eternal objects." then there is god, consciousness, cosmos.

There are so many things.

## Help needed.

1. suggest fewer technical resources and focus on the process philosophy.
2. it can be possible that I have never seeseenseesee see seen such a thing before, which makes me uncomfortable with these ideas. So tell me something that makes me need the picture in this philosophy.
3. is it worth spending time to understand this?
4. tell me where to start?

Comment: Se  [Whitehead](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/whitehead/) and [Process phylosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/process-philosophy/)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA How would process philosophy be compatible with the idea that space/time is emergent, as in, e.g., this Edward Witten interview, https://www.quantamagazine.org/edward-witten-ponders-the-nature-of-reality-20171128 Because now, time isn't even fundamental, so neither can be process. Rather, there must be a deeper layer that gives rise to both. And process philosophy would be entirely overlooking this more fundamental layer of reality.

Comment: But "process philosophy" has been recently involved into [modern discussions about foundations of physical theory](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110753707-016/html)